# jQuery - Assigning Image src to variable assigns image data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse an Amazon book product page. When assigning the img src URL to a variable, like from [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0553524267](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553524267)

```
var image = $('#imgBlkFront').attr('src').split(/_(.+)?/)[0] + "jpg";
```

or

```
var image = document.getElementById("imgBlkFront").src.split(/_(.+)?/)[0] + "jpg";
```

The variable ends up being the image data: "data:image/jpeg:base64…". What I'd like to get is the http:// URL.

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: Are you sure that's not the actual image source? Can you link to the page you are trying to parse?

Comment: Can't get a url that doesn't exist

Comment: @charlietfl I was trying a book product page. Didn't notice that the image Ids are different for other products.

Comment: @empedocle, if you meant something else or you are not understanding my answer, let me know so I can help

Comment: @AmmarCSE Thank you. I could use some help. I'm not setting the src of an img element but trying to get it and assign it to a variable. It's the variable that's not ending up as a traditional URL as I'd like.

Comment: @empedocle, what do you intend to do with the URL variable eventually?

Answer (score 2):

This is because setting the `src` of an `img` element to [**base64**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html) encoded data is a valid route of setting the source.

What is happening is `jQuery` is functioning correctly by returning the `src` attribute, but it so happens that the attribute value is a `base64` encoded string instead of a traditional `url`